# Horizontal scroll tabs for bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I currently have is a row that uses the overflow property in `col-xs-2`'s CSS to contain a horizontal scrollable box to display elements:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <c:if test="${!empty form.dataBase}">  
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2" style="margin-top:20px;">
            ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </c:if>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .col-xs-2 {
    width: 102%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-xs-2 {
    width: 35%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

What I want to add to this box are tabs that would scroll when the mouse hovers over them, similar to how a site like [amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00WMO9LT8) would show the "Customers Who Bought This Item Also Bought" tabs on the sides of the box, but instead of going to a new page, would advance the scroll with hover. How would I do this?

This is using bootstrap

Comment: You basically want to use a bootstrap carousel it seems. This might help you get started on a solution:  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel It will most likely also require some js to work the way you want it to.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I might have to use the carousel, but wanted to see if anyone knew another way.